# List of OYBAccountIDs and Business Unit Names

Tags: marketing-cloud, admin, sfmc-business-unit

Is  there an admin view, system data view or something else where the OBYAccountID is listed next to the Business Unit name. 
e.g.

```
AccountID    OBYAccountID   BU Name
    1234     0003           Test03
    1234     0047           Test09
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a dataview, and the only place in the UI where the AccountID (MID) is listed is in the BU switcher dropdown. AccountID is the EID (Parent/Top level) while the OYBAccountID is the Child BU MID.

You can also make a retrieve request using SOAP:

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>BusinessUnit</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hover over the business units in the admin section and the url description at the bottom left of a browser will give the MID at the end of the URL something like the following as an example: ..."id=12345" in the Parent Business Unit. If you have many business units, you can increase the number of business units to view on the page as follows: 25, 50, 75 or 100

Comment: Updated my answer to provide SOAP API call