# API Permission issue while Retrieve List of all the Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to retrieve all the Business Units using the below SOAP request as mentioned in the post: [List of OYBAccountIDs and Business Unit Names](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281859/list-of-oybaccountids-and-business-unit-names)

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <RetrieveRequest>
      <ObjectType>BusinessUnit</ObjectType>
      <Properties>ID</Properties>
      <Properties>Name</Properties>
      <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
    </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
```

But i am getting the response as "**Error: API Permission Failed.**".
Is there any permission that we need to give for the API User? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Installed Package Component Scope, make sure that Provisioning > Accounts has 'Read' access. Note that if you update the scope in an existing Installed Package, changes will take 5 minutes to propagate. So go and make a cup of tea, then come back and get a new access token and try your request once again.

[image: Installed Package Scope]

Answer (score 0):

If using SOAP, there is a known bug where you need to activate both "READ" and "WRITE" permissions to get it to work.